# How to order effects in jquery sequentially

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this snippet of code:

```
$("a#list-mode").click(function() {
  $("#list-fix-pos").removeClass('col-lg-3', 1250, "easeInOutQuart" );
  $(this).hide("fade", 1250, true);
  $("a#map-mode").show("fade", 1250, true);
});
```

How can I order the effects so that they take place sequentially? At the moment, all effects transition at once.

Thanks

Comment: there are different ways to order the effect of the animation you wanted to achieve, you can use setTimeout or $.delay()

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery event order and waiting till animation complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407592/jquery-event-order-and-waiting-till-animation-complete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.hide` and `.show` functions allow you to specify a function to be performed upon completion. The syntax is

```
.hide( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

In your case, that'd be

```
$("a#list-mode").click(function() {
    $("#list-fix-pos").hide(1250, 'easeInOutQuart', function() {
        $(this).hide(1250, 'fade', function() {
            $("a#map-mode").show(1250, 'fade');
        });
    });
    $("#list-fix-pos").removeClass('col-lg-3');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options

- use complete callbacks
- use promises returned by element when they have animation going on
- use `.delay()`

3rd case is simplest and keep code cleaner

```
$(...).animate(duration1,...)...
$(...).delay(duration1).animate(duration2,...)...
```

And just fyi with promises:

```
$(...).animate().promise().pipe(...)
```

or something like

```
$.when($(...).animate(...).promise())
 .then(function (){ return $(...).animate(...).promise() })
 .then(function (){ return $(...).animate(...).promise() })
 ...
```

which will look quite nice if you give functions names

```
function hideButton() { return $(...).animate().promise() }
function showMenu() { return $(...).animate().promise() }

$.when(hideButton).then(showMenu)
```