# Executing code when a function is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in my code that animates several elements. What I'm wanting to do is execute a sequence of code but **only after** this function has completed.

Say for example I had this:

```
executeMyAnimationFunction();

// Execute this code AFTER executeMyAnimationFunction() has completed
alert('test');
```

So far I've tried using setTimeout but this doesn't seem to be very reliable. I've also tried using .promise() but this doesn't seem to execute properly either:

```
$(executeMyAnimationFunction()).promise().done(function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

However I admit I be using it incorrectly. In [the demo](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) on the jquery site, it seems promise() is being used on the elements that are being animated. I tried doing it like this:

```
$('#myAnimatedElement').promise().done(function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

and it *seemed* to work in certain scenarios but in others it didn't work. I wonder if this is a reliable way of using promise()?

Basically I'm stuck now with how I can do this. All I want to do is wait until a function has fully executed (the function simply animates a group of elements) and then continue with the execution of my code.

Is there a simple way of doing this using jquery/javascript that I'm missing?

Thanks

EDIT: To show my problem in a little more detail, here is the exact code I'm using:

```
<script>
        $(function () {

            $(window).bind('hashchange', function (e) {
                if ($(':animated').length) {
                    return false;
                }

                var section = $.param.fragment();
                var current = $('#content').children(':visible').attr('id');

                $('a').removeClass('active');                

                // If this is the first load of the page, then animate in the initial content
                if (section === '') {                    
                    if (current === 'reception') {
                        animateContentIn("reception");                        
                    }
                    else {                        
                        $('a[href="#' + section + '"]').addClass('active');

                        // Animate out existing content
                        animateContentOut(current);

                        setTimeout(function () {
                            animateContentIn("reception");
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Otherwise find the current page content and animate out
                    animateContentOut(current);

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        animateContentIn(section);
                    }, 1000);
                }               
            })

            // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
            // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
            $(window).trigger('hashchange');
        });       

        function animateContentIn(activePage) { 
            // Now animate in the new content
            switch (activePage) {
                case "floorspace":
                    animateFloorspaceElementsIn();
                    break;
                case "reception":
                    animateReceptionElementsIn();
                    break;
            }
        }

        function animateContentOut(currentPage) {
            // Now animate in the new content
            switch (currentPage) {
                case "floorspace":                    
                    animateFloorspaceElementsOut();
                    break;
                case "reception":
                    animateReceptionElementsOut();
                    break;
            }
        }

        function animateReceptionElementsIn() {
            $('#reception').show();

            $('#reception .title').animate({
                bottom: 520
            }, 400);

            $('#reception .tile1').animate({
                bottom: 504
            }, 600);

            $('#reception .tile2').animate({
                bottom: 504
            }, 700);

            $('#reception .hero').animate({
                bottom: 40
            }, 1000);

            $('#reception .content1').animate({
                bottom: 8
            }, 400);

            $('#reception .content2').animate({
                bottom: 8
            }, 500);
        }

        function animateReceptionElementsOut() {
            $('#reception .title').animate({
                bottom: -56
            }, 400);

            $('#reception .tile1').animate({
                bottom: -136
            }, 600);

            $('#reception .tile2').animate({
                bottom: -152
            }, 700);

            $('#reception .hero').animate({
                bottom: -464
            }, 1000, function () {
                $('#reception').hide();
            });

            $('#reception .content1').animate({
                bottom: -112
            }, 400);

            $('#reception .content2').animate({
                bottom: -104
            }, 500);
        }

        function animateFloorspaceElementsIn() {
            $('#floorspace').show();

            $('#floorspace .title').animate({
                bottom: 520
            }, 400);

            $('#floorspace .tile1').animate({
                bottom: 504
            }, 600);

            $('#floorspace .tile2').animate({
                bottom: 504
            }, 700);

            $('#floorspace .hero').animate({
                bottom: 40
            }, 1000);

            $('#floorspace .content1').animate({
                bottom: 8
            }, 400);

            $('#floorspace .content2').animate({
                bottom: 8
            }, 500);
        }

        function animateFloorspaceElementsOut() {
            $('#floorspace .title').animate({
                bottom: -56
            }, 400);

            $('#floorspace .tile1').animate({
                bottom: -136
            }, 600);

            $('#floorspace .tile2').animate({
                bottom: -152
            }, 700);

            $('#floorspace .hero').animate({
                bottom: -464
            }, 1000, function () {
                $('#floorspace').hide();
            });

            $('#floorspace .content1').animate({
                bottom: -112
            }, 400);

            $('#floorspace .content2').animate({
                bottom: -104
            }, 500);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="vert-wrapper">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <aside id="sidebar">
                <nav id="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Building</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#reception">Reception</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#floorspace">Floor Space</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Views</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terraces</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Specification</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Plans</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ten Storeys</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </aside>  
            <div id="content">
                <article id="reception">
                    <h1 class="title">
                        <img src="/images/reception/title.png" alt="Edge" />
                    </h1>
                    <img src="/images/reception/1.jpg" alt="" class="tile1" />
                    <img src="/images/reception/2.jpg" alt="" class="tile2" />
                    <img src="/images/reception/hero.jpg" alt="" class="hero" />
                    <img src="/images/reception/content1.jpg" alt="" class="content1" />
                    <img src="/images/reception/content2.jpg" alt="" class="content2" />
                </article>
                <article id="floorspace">
                    <h1 class="title">
                        <img src="/images/floorspace/title.png" alt="Space" />
                    </h1>
                    <img src="/images/floorspace/1.jpg" alt="" class="tile1" />
                    <img src="/images/floorspace/2.jpg" alt="" class="tile2" />
                    <img src="/images/floorspace/hero.jpg" alt="" class="hero" />
                    <img src="/images/floorspace/content1.jpg" alt="" class="content1" />
                    <img src="/images/floorspace/content2.jpg" alt="" class="content2" />
                </article>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now the code I have above does work, however I don't feel it's very clean nor does it seem to execute correctly 100% of the time.

Basically the dilemma I have is I want to be able to execute animateContentIn() **after** animateContentOut() has finished. The only way I've managed to do this is to delay the animateContentIn() function by the time it takes to do the longest animation - in this case it's 1000ms.

Isn't there a tidier, more efficient way of writing this??

Comment: share the code inside `executeMyAnimationFunction`

Comment: Add a callback to your executeMyAnimationFunction function.

Comment: why don't you use the callback function of animation itself

Comment: most of the animation functions inside jQuery have a `complete` argument where you can pass a callback function to be called when the animation is complete.

Answer (score 4):

```
function someRandomFunction(){
    // This will be executed after myFirstFunction
}

function myFirstFunction(callbackFunction){
    // Do some stuff
    alert(1);
    // Do something slow here

    // Callback when done:
    callbackFunction(some, input);
}
// Usage:
myFirstFunction( someRandomFunction ); // with existing function
myFirstFunction( function(){ alert(1);} ); // anonymous
```

Note: You can use anonymous functions
Small Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zcp82/2/

Another topic with good info: [Create a custom callback in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/create-a-custom-callback-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Use a callback?

```
function executeMyAnimationFunction(complete){
    $('div').animate({ height: '1px' }, 500, complete);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
executeMyAnimationFunction(function(){
    console.log('animation complete');
});
```

Or if you insist on using promises:

```
executeMyAnimationFunction(){
    var dfd = $.deferred();

    $('div').animate({ height: '1px' }, 500, function(){
        dfd.resolve();
    });

    return dfd.promise();
}

executeMyAnimationFunction().done(function(){
    console.log('animation complete');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [`Old Post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407592/jquery-event-order-and-waiting-till-animation-complete)

This seem like duplicate question, if you call multiple function it will call in sequence only